# R AzureGraph functions return Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, microsoft-graph-api

I have just started exploring the R AzureGraph package to use a REST Graph API but I haven't gone very far.

My code is very simple:

```
Version <- "v1.0"
TenantID <- "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
Endpoint <- paste0("https://graph.microsoft.com/", Version, "/communications/callRecords/")
Token <- paste0("https://login.microsoftonline.com/", TenantID, "/oauth2/v2.0/token")

Dataset <- call_graph_url(Token, Endpoint, body = NULL, encode = "json", 
                          http_verb = "GET", 
                          http_status_handler = "message", 
                          simplify = FALSE, 
                          auto_refresh = TRUE
                          )
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any suggestion would really be appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `token` argument to `call_graph_url` should be a token *object*, obtained by calling `AzureAuth::get_azure_token`.

```r
tok <- AzureAuth::get_azure_token(
    "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "tenant_id",
    # ... other authentication arguments
)

call_graph_url(
    tok,
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/...",
    # other Graph arguments
)
```

In general, however, you shouldn't be calling this directly. Instead, use `create_graph_login()` to authenticate and create a Graph session object. See the [Introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureGraph/vignettes/intro.html) and [Authentication vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureGraph/vignettes/auth.html) for more details.

Also, it looks like you're trying to use the [call records API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Be aware that the default app registration supplied with AzureGraph doesn't let you work with this API. Instead, you'll need to create your own app registration with the necessary permissions and use that instead. The Authentication vignette also discusses this, in the "Creating a custom app registration" section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! It's the first time I try to use the Graph API. I read the instructions and will follow through to register the app. Thanks again!

Comment: I used a pre-existing app registration. I can log in , but when I run the token I get this error message: 'Error in process_aad_response(res) : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to obtain Azure Active Directory token. Message:
AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/ was not found in the tenant named SOFTEL Communications Inc.. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.'

Comment: Could it be permissions or is it the code? The app information is correct. Tok <- AzureAuth::get_azure_token(Endpoint, TenantID, app = AppID, password = Secret)